# Finding the difference between last two inserted rows in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Finding the difference between last two inserted rows in mysql

I have table similarly,

Test 
name max min timestamp
abc  30  10   xxxxx
abc  60   5   xxxxxx
abc  90   23   xxxxxxx
abc1  30  10   xxxxx
abc1  60   5   xxxxxx
abc1  90   23   xxxxxxx
......
.....

I need find the difference between last two inserted rows like
abc   30   18
abc1  30   18

Using mysql i need the values.

Comment: Can you write clearly what are your those 2 rows... and what you want to see in output.. and mainly "WHAT ALL DID YOU TRY"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to the database? Are the rows being inserted by your program, or are the already in said database? What exactly are the column names in the database? Is the timestamp from when the record was inserted into the database?

Assuming you are already connected, the timestamp is when the record was inserted, the rows are not being inserted by your program, and you are confused on the SQL aspect of it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM %database name%
ORDER BY %timestamp name% DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Then, you want to compare each of the values.